# jQuery imgAreaSelect not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, image, mobile

In one of our project we have used "imgAreaSelect" plugin for cropping and re-sizing an image. Although it's working fine on desktop computers, but on mobile devices it is not working at all.

Is there any work around to handle this problem, or any other plugin with same features that should work on both desktop and mobile devices?

Answer (score 6):

There was a mobile support added by plugin author into mobile branch (see article [here](http://odyniec.net/blog/category/projects/imgareaselect/)). 
It has some bug with selection display. This bug is fixed in [this](https://github.com/odyniec/imgareaselect/blob/0ecc52a53ca6a37ed83a09f9f684a805abd0b3ba/jquery.imgareaselect.js) branch which was not yet merged to main branch but it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just make a fork from the original code with mobile support.

https://github.com/javenosa/imgareaselect

Comment: hi HolloW love that you did this. Is this backwards compatible with the original though? I can't seem to get it working with my old code...

Comment: @MarMan29 Yes, is compatible, I already used over my project and works fine.

Comment: @HolloW thanks for the contribution, today I tested your code and it was working fine, except a weird effect on the .imgareaselect-outer that wasn't following the selection, instead, it was going the opposite direction. Is there any updates or fix for this issue? Thanks.